# How to speed up a jQuery image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a webpage and I'm trying to speed up the time it takes to load the images in the gallery. You can view the gallery here:

```
www.imagethrow.com/design-studio-all-throws.html
```

This is the HTML part of the gallery:

```
<a class="imgLink" href="path-to-the-image.jpg">Image name</a>
<img src="" id="theImage">
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.imgLink').click(function(){
        var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#theImage').attr('src',imgPath);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The images have been optimized/compressed and I've implemented cache control settings. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve it through preloading. You can either choose to preload them all, or preload them as the user hovers over the links.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.imgLink').click(function(){
        var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#theImage').attr('src',imgPath);
        return false;
    }).one("mouseenter",function(){
        var img = createElement("img");
        img.src = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Would be even better if you can have it start preloading when the user hovers *near* the link rather than waiting till they actually hover over the link itself.

Comment: I will try this... Is the above code for preloading when the users hover near the links or to preload all of them?

Comment: it preloads when the user hovers over the link. if they click really fast or it takes a few seconds to load they may still click before it's done loading.

Comment: Where do I place the code? Do I replace the current code posted in my original comment?

Comment: Yes, it's a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

**Jpg instead of Png**

Use Jpg images instead of Png. 
A picture like http://www.imagethrow.com/img/design-studio/2.5_Layer_Throw/Little_Caesars.png can easily be brought back from 380KB to about 100 KB if you save it in high quality (80) Jpg.

Note that Jpg doesn't support transparency, so you have to make the transparent edges white in the pictures.

Also Jpg is lossy, that means that a slight amount of detail will be lost when saving the picture. This is hardly noticable, though, especially not for pictures. Besides, you can play around and choose the optimal balance between file size and quality.

**WebP**

If that still isn't enough, you might try [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?csw=1), a brand new image format by Google, but obviously it is not supported by all browsers at the moment, so I don't think you should start using this, or only as a last resort and with proper fallbacks.

**Preloading**

Apart from that, you might preload the images. That means that you start loading all the images in the background. However, I wouldn't recommend it for a gallery like this. Users will probably not open every image, and preloading takes a lot of bandwidth. Especially for users on a limited (mobile) data plan, it's not very nice if you download multiple megabytes of images in the background, when they don't even want to see them all.